# How to sort one array using another array?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am building an Angular 9 app.
In this app I need to sort one array using another array.

**This is the first array:**

```
[{
    "field_key": "title",
    "field_type": "text",
    "field_label": "Title",
    "rows": [{
        "id": 267255299,
        "content": "Personal task"
    }, {
        "id": 568449863,
        "content": "Super"
    }, {
        "id": 110557130,
        "content": "Another child"
    }, {
        "id": 365047528,
        "content": "Another task"
    }, {
        "id": 383976941,
        "content": "Nice"
    }, {
        "id": 811735335,
        "content": "Arrays"
    }, {
        "id": 324862914,
        "content": "Arrays"
    }, {
        "id": 485226870,
        "content": "Yay a child"
    }, {
        "id": 276334971,
        "content": "My new task"
    }, {
        "id": 549277506,
        "content": "Douplicatee"
    }]
}, {
    "field_key": "progress",
    "field_type": "progress",
    "field_label": "Progress",
    "rows": [{
        "id": 267255299,
        "content": null
    }, {
        "id": 568449863,
        "content": null
    }, {
        "id": 110557130,
        "content": 100
    }, {
        "id": 365047528,
        "content": 100
    }, {
        "id": 383976941,
        "content": null
    }, {
        "id": 811735335,
        "content": null
    }, {
        "id": 324862914,
        "content": 100
    }, {
        "id": 485226870,
        "content": null
    }, {
        "id": 276334971,
        "content": 60
    }, {
        "id": 549277506,
        "content": 0
    }]
}, {
    "field_key": "ends_at_date",
    "field_type": "date",
    "field_label": "Due date",
    "rows": [{
        "id": 267255299,
        "content": null
    }, {
        "id": 568449863,
        "content": null
    }, {
        "id": 110557130,
        "content": null
    }, {
        "id": 365047528,
        "content": null
    }, {
        "id": 383976941,
        "content": null
    }, {
        "id": 811735335,
        "content": null
    }, {
        "id": 324862914,
        "content": null
    }, {
        "id": 485226870,
        "content": "2020-08-25"
    }, {
        "id": 276334971,
        "content": "2020-08-16"
    }, {
        "id": 549277506,
        "content": null
    }]
}]
```

**This is the array I want to use to sort the first array. The "key" key in the second array is the same value as the "field_key" in the first array. So I guess I should be able to use these values to do the sorting.**

```
[{
      key: 'title',
      label: 'Title',
      field: 'text',
      visible: true
    }, {
      key: 'ends_at_date',
      label: 'Due date',
      field: 'date',
      visible: true
    }, {
      key: 'progress',
      label: 'Progress',
      field: 'progress',
      visible: true
    }]
```

I want to reorder/sort the first array so that it is in the same order as the last array based upon the key/field_key values. Right now the order of the first array is: Title, Progress, Ends_at_date but the order of the second array (the correct one) is Title, Ends_at_date, Progress.

Comment: Do you really mean sorting or do you maybe mean filtering? I really don't get what you want to sort here.

Comment: I want to reorder/sort the first array so that it is in the same order as the last array based upon the key/field_key values. Right now the order of the first array is: Title, Progress, Ends_at_date but the order of the second array (the correct one) is Title, Ends_at_date, Progress.

Comment: So, all the side data doesn't matter, you just want the indexes of the first array to match the order of appearance in the second array?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment you requirements are now clearer. Please try

```
const array1 = [{
    "field_key": "title",
    "field_type": "text",
    "field_label": "Title",
}, {
    "field_key": "progress",
    "field_type": "progress",
    "field_label": "Progress",
}, {
    "field_key": "ends_at_date",
    "field_type": "date",
    "field_label": "Due date",
}];

const array2 = [{
      key: 'title',
      label: 'Title',
      field: 'text',
      visible: true
    }, {
      key: 'ends_at_date',
      label: 'Due date',
      field: 'date',
      visible: true
    }, {
      key: 'progress',
      label: 'Progress',
      field: 'progress',
      visible: true
    }];

const sorted = array1.sort((left, right) => array2.findIndex(sortKey => sortKey.key === left.field_key) - array2.findIndex(sortKey => sortKey.key === right.field_key));

console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do an in-place sort, I guess you could just get the indexes of the different keys, and then just set the indexes of a resulting array as in the example below

```js
const array1 = [{
    "field_key": "title",
    "field_type": "text",
    "field_label": "Title",
    "rows": [{
        "id": 267255299,
        "content": "Personal task"
    }, {
        "id": 568449863,
        "content": "Super"
    }, {
        "id": 110557130,
        "content": "Another child"
    }, {
        "id": 365047528,
        "content": "Another task"
    }, {
        "id": 383976941,
        "content": "Nice"
    }, {
        "id": 811735335,
        "content": "Arrays"
    }, {
        "id": 324862914,
        "content": "Arrays"
    }, {
        "id": 485226870,
        "content": "Yay a child"
    }, {
        "id": 276334971,
        "content": "My new task"
    }, {
        "id": 549277506,
        "content": "Douplicatee"
    }]
}, {
    "field_key": "progress",
    "field_type": "progress",
    "field_label": "Progress",
    "rows": [{
        "id": 267255299,
        "content": null
    }, {
        "id": 568449863,
        "content": null
    }, {
        "id": 110557130,
        "content": 100
    }, {
        "id": 365047528,
        "content": 100
    }, {
        "id": 383976941,
        "content": null
    }, {
        "id": 811735335,
        "content": null
    }, {
        "id": 324862914,
        "content": 100
    }, {
        "id": 485226870,
        "content": null
    }, {
        "id": 276334971,
        "content": 60
    }, {
        "id": 549277506,
        "content": 0
    }]
}, {
    "field_key": "ends_at_date",
    "field_type": "date",
    "field_label": "Due date",
    "rows": [{
        "id": 267255299,
        "content": null
    }, {
        "id": 568449863,
        "content": null
    }, {
        "id": 110557130,
        "content": null
    }, {
        "id": 365047528,
        "content": null
    }, {
        "id": 383976941,
        "content": null
    }, {
        "id": 811735335,
        "content": null
    }, {
        "id": 324862914,
        "content": null
    }, {
        "id": 485226870,
        "content": "2020-08-25"
    }, {
        "id": 276334971,
        "content": "2020-08-16"
    }, {
        "id": 549277506,
        "content": null
    }]
}];

const array2 = [{
      key: 'title',
      label: 'Title',
      field: 'text',
      visible: true
    }, {
      key: 'ends_at_date',
      label: 'Due date',
      field: 'date',
      visible: true
    }, {
      key: 'progress',
      label: 'Progress',
      field: 'progress',
      visible: true
    }];
    
    
function sortByAppearance( array1, array2 ) {
  const dict = Object.assign({}, ...array2.map( (v, i) => ({ [v.key]: i }) ) );
  const result = Array(array1.length);
  for (let value of array1) {
    result[dict[value.field_key]] = value;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log( sortByAppearance( array1, array2 ) );
```